# What are the differences between 'hard' and 'normal' difficulties?

Tags: pid

There is an achievement in Planet in Distress for completing the game on hard. I am not sure if it's worth my time to pursue this achievement. How's hard different from normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard Mode redesigns levels with extra obstacles that significantly increase the difficulty. According to the developers, it is intended as a "nightmare" challenge.

> Two of our team members had an ambition to take the game further; especially the core mechanic. The light beams were considered to have more depth than what had been seen in the game. A new game difficulty setting was created to explore the idea: Pid’s Hard Mode.
>
> [...] Hard Mode had turned the cheerful learning curve of Pid into a nightmare. The game was no longer a tasteful balance between the different elements. It was now primarily about the interaction and that alone.
>
> <sub>Source: *[Pid: A PSN platforming adventure with a difference - Playstation Blog](https://blog.playstation.com/archive/2012/10/05/pid-a-psn-platforming-adventure-with-a-difference/)*</sub>

An [Easy Mode was also added in an update](https://www.engadget.com/2012-12-04-pid-receives-easy-mode-on-pc.html?guccounter=1) that redesigns levels, shortens boss fights, and has less crowded environments for easier navigation.